# What is effective spindle count

Tags: postgresql, max-connections

The [PostgresSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) suggest a rule for find the optimal amount of DB connection pool size.

amount = ((core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)

But it does not explain what the effective spindle count is and how can I find this value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This relates to rotating harddisks (not SSDs). One rotating harddisk is one spindle.

So if your server uses e.g. a RAID with 16 disks, then your effective_spindle_count is 16

It is essentially a measure of how many concurrent I/O request your server can manage. Rotating harddisks can (typically) only handle one I/O request at a time. If you have 16, your system can handle 16 I/O requests at the same time.

The mentioned rule of thumb is no longer valid for SSDs. As they can typically handle several parallel I/O requests at the same time. I don't know however how you could obtain that number.

Which is also mentioned in the Wiki page you linked to:

> *There hasn't been any analysis so far regarding how well the formula works with SSDs.*

Comment: That wiki page was last updated nearly 5 years ago, and the advice in question is [even older](https://web.archive.org/web/20120828112429/https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections). I/O queue depth might be more relevant today than the number of spindles, even if  the latter are actually present.